# Using Regular Expression for Phone Number

Tags: c#, regex

I know this question is asked like a thousand times in here, but I can't get the hang of it yet. I need help with checking a textbox if it matches a Phone Number format. The format should be likes this :

`000-000-000` or `(+000)00-000-000`. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Show your current code related to the question.

Answer (score 5):

give this pattern a try,

```
^(\(\+\d{3}\)|\d)\d{2}(-\d{3}){2}$
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Generated Explanation:

- Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) `^`
- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `(\(\+\d{3}\)|\d)`

  - Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `\(\+\d{3}\)`

    - Match the character “(” literally `\(`
    - Match the character “+” literally `\+`
    - Match a single digit 0..9 `\d{3}`

      - Exactly 3 times `{3}`
    - Match the character “)” literally `\)`
  - Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `\d`

    - Match a single digit 0..9 `\d`
- Match a single digit 0..9 `\d{2}`

  - Exactly 2 times `{2}`
- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 `(-\d{3}){2}`

  - Exactly 2 times `{2}`
  - Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. `{2}`
  - Match the character “-” literally `-`
  - Match a single digit 0..9 `\d{3}`

    - Exactly 3 times `{3}`
- Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) `$`

Answer (score 1):

Pattern 1 is `\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{3}`

Pattern 2 is `\(\+\d{3}\)\d{2}\-d{3}\-\d{3}`

So you need to match for Pattern1 OR Pattern2:

```
(\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{3})|(\(\+\d{3}\)\d{2}\-d{3}\-\d{3})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:\d|\(\+\d{3}\))\d{2}(?:-\d{3}){2}
```

Or, if you're regarding of performance, better change it to:

```
(?:\(\+\d{3}\)|\d)\d{2}(?:-\d{3}){2}
```